# How much total damage can a 3rd-level Ranger with 2 shortswords and the Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style deal in one round?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, two-weapon-fighting

How much damage can a 3rd level Ranger with 2 short swords (with *Two- Weapon Fighting* fighting style) deal in total during a round?
The Ranger rolls 2d20 and hits the enemy with both (with no bonus or penalty or advantage), so he can roll the damage dice: 1d6+6 (strength bonus + proficiency) and 1d6+6 (strength bonus + proficiency). Is this correct?

Comment: ok, I make a mistake (not only one): the damage dice is 1d6+4 (not 1d6+6 sorry) for each hand/weapon. Total: 1d6+4 +1d6+4

Comment: Your +4 would suggest an ability score of at least 18, which is not possible with standard array by level 3, only if you roll for your ability scores. Is that on purpose? Also, are you interested primarily in what this default damage baseline is, or what the damage woudl be for a special subclass of ranger (as that may differ)?

Comment: Recall that you can modify your post, correcting the eventual errors/typos that are present.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin Yes the Ranger has Strength 18 cause we use to roll 7 series and choose 6 and he gave 17 to strength plus +1 for the human race. No restrictions.

Comment: @Eddymage Can I edit my question again and correct "1d6+6" to "1d6+4"? If I, then some comment/question/answer in this page loose meaning. Or not?

Comment: It was a suggestion for future questions and/or posts. Do not bother about "invalidating" comments, since they are meant to be temporary: see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) in the [help].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You don't add proficiency bonus to damage

You only add your proficiency bonus to your to hit, not to your damage, so you would be doing 1d6+4 with either attack. This is explained in the Combat chapter, *PHB*, p. *194*, for attack rolls:

> When a character makes an attack roll, the two most common modifiers to the roll are an **ability modifier and the character’s proficiency bonus**

vs. *PHB*, p. 196, for Damage:

> When attacking with a weapon, you add **your ability modifier**—the same modifier used for the attack roll—to the damage.

No proficiency bonus here.

#### Two-weapon fighting

Normally, when you fight with two light melee weapons like short swords, one in each hand, you do not get to add your ability modifier to the damage from your off hand (*PHB*, p. 195):

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. **You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack**, unless that modifier is negative.

However, on 2nd level, the ranger can pick the Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style, so they get to add their ability modifier to the second attack:

> When you engage in two-weapon fighting, **you can add your ability modifier to the damage of the second attack**.

Assuming an ability score of 18<sup>1</sup> for a +4 bonus, if you pick the Two-Weapon Fighting fighting style, you get to deal 1d6 +4 (ability modifier) with either short sword, for a total of 2d6+8 if both attacks hit.

Depending on what Ranger archetype you pick, and on your opponents, you will get additional bonuses to your damage. For example, with Colossus Slayer you would get to add another d8 damage if your foe is under their hit point maximum.

---

<sup>1</sup> You confirmed in comments that you have an ability score of 18 for Strength, from your homebrew method of rolling stats by rolling 7 sets of 3d6, and keeping and allocating the 6 highest results, then applying racial modifiers.

Comment: Which subclass did you calculate this on? They'll have different damage outputs.

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike Fair point, I think they are wanting to understand how 2-weapon fighting would work but that surely would influence it (like many other things, added a note on it.

Comment: Why guess what they want? Just ask them to clarify :)

Comment: Clear, so with ability bonus +4 and "Two- Weapon Fighting"as  fighting style, a 3rd level Ranger roll 1d6+4 for the main hand and 1d6+4 for the second hand.

Comment: I think you mean ability score of 18 for a +4 bonus, not 16.

Comment: @smbailey Yes, I do, as that is the implied assumption by the quearant. I'll add a footnote because normally on tier 1, with point buy you only would get to +3

Comment: Why are you going with implied assumptions and guesses? If you want to really help OP, get the details so you can give them what they need.

Comment: @NautArchisonstrike I will follow your advise and ask them confirmatory questions.

Comment: Ok, I confirm: I got ability score of 18, we use a particular style to roll dice in creation: we roll 7 series of 3d6, then we choose the 6 better, then we apply each one on each ability. The human race did the next. I've got Strenght 18 and so +4 mod.